# Do 3d charts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, graph, graphics

Hi I need do a 3d charts in JavaScript, I prove a lot of librarys for example: ploty but I didn't find some library.
Do we know someone??
I need do someone similar like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

RGraph has a few 3D chart types available - there are demos that show them all in the download archive:

https://www.rgraph.net/download.html#stable

The filenames are:

```
demos/bar-3d-effect-multi-row.html
demos/bar-3d-effect-xaxispos-center.html
demos/bar-3d-effect.html
demos/bipolar-3d.html
demos/hbar-3d-hprogress.html
demos/hbar-3d-yaxispos-center.html
demos/hbar-3d-yaxispos-right.html
demos/hbar-3d.html
demos/rose-3d.html
demos/donut-3d-shadow.html
demos/donut-3d.html
demos/pie-3d.html
demos/svg-bar-3d-grouped-negative.html
demos/svg-bar-3d-grouped.html
demos/svg-bar-3d-stacked.html
demos/svg-bar-3d-standard.html
demos/svg-bar-3d-vprogress.html
demos/pie-3d-html-key.html
```